# Python CGI script is downloading instead of running

Tags: python, apache2, cgi

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04LTS with apache2. I working on executing a simple CGI python script "hello.py". But instead of executing the file, it is getting downloaded. If I change the extension from ".py" to ".cgi", the code is displaying in my browser.

My CGI script is saved in /var/www/cgi-bin directory and it is written below

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()    
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

I have followed [CGI tutorial](https://tasdikrahman.me/2015/09/30/Running-CGI-Scripts-on-Apache2-Ubuntu/). This tutorial is following ScriptAlias method to configure apache2. As per the tutorial, I have added the below code to the end of the apche2.conf file

```
#########     Adding capaility to run CGI-scripts #################
ServerName localhost
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py
```

And I have changed my conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf file into below form

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
        <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
                Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
                Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
        </IfModule>

        <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
                ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
                <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
                        AllowOverride None
                        Options +ExecCGI
                        #Require all granted
                </Directory>
        </IfDefine>
</IfModule>
```

Still my CGI script is downloading instead of running. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Welcome, have a look here and see if you've forgotten anything: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html *(such as `LoadModule`)*

Comment: Thank you for your support. I have fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it.
After editing config files, there is one more step to do.In `/etc/apache2/mods-available` directory you can see the installed modules of apache2. `cgi.load` is the module for CGI files. It is not enabled by default. Use these commands to enable them.

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
$ sudo ln -s ../mods-available/cgi.load
```

Then reload the server

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
```